# distinct on 4 billion records

Tags: sql, teradata

In Teradata
Consider a scenario where we have more than 4 billion records in a table and need to execute DISTINCT/GROUP BY on a column which is not part of primary or secondary index and not partitioned.

Now this is taking too much time.
Is there any other way of achieving this.

This is a standalone environment , so I can not copy data from it and neither I have access to create a new table in this environment. Its just SELECT access I have.

Comment: Then add a key for that column.

Comment: can you please provide a syntax,its a production environment

Comment: 1. this is easily googleable and 2. never apply changes on a production system without testing in a test environment.

Comment: If you only have SELECT access, you cannot create a new index, and if you have to ask how to create an index you really shouldn't be operating on a 4 billion row production enviroment...

Comment: hey I know how to create index :) , its just that this is a  PROD environment do I really dont want to play here and its just select access I have , btw thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the number of unique values for the column `HELP STATISTICS {database}.{tablename}` will provide you the columns with statistics and the number of unique values. In Teradata 14 or later, you can perform `SHOW STATISTICS VALUES COLUMN {column} ON {database}.{tablename};` This command will provide you more details about the histograms including the biased values for the column. The biased values may encompass all of the unique values for the column or just the first few hundred. Your permissions on the table may or may not permit this.

If using statistics is out of the question because they don't exist or you don't have sufficient permissions then you are going to end up scanning the table. Even having statistics collected on the column to get this information will result in a full table scan.

Finally, depending on the table and the column which you are investigating you may find that the data dictionary maintained by the data modeler(s) will have the expected domain for this column. They may have completed data profiling against this table to obtain this information.